# In terraform making string variable optional in action block

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi i am creating  alert rules. For some of the alerts i dont need to send any notification using action group.For that i need to make action group variable (string) as optional.

I tried using condition like var.action_group_id != null action_group_id : "". But i am getting following error.

> Error: Can not parse "action.0.action_group_id" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "null": invalid URI for request

And i tried making action block as dynamic block but it is not iterable. for_each is not supporting dynamic block with single variable with one values.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "keyvault_alert" {

 for_each = var.keyvault_alert_rules

  name                = "${var.kv_name} - ${each.value.severity}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  description         = each.value.description
  scopes              = var.alert_scope
  severity            = each.value.severity
  frequency           = each.value.frequency
  `window_size         = each.value.windowsize`

# criteria block
  criteria {
    
    metric_namespace  = "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
    threshold         = each.value.threshold
    metric_name       = each.value.metric_name
    aggregation       = each.value.aggregation
    operator          = each.value.operator

 # dimension block

    dynamic "dimension" {
      for_each = each.value.dimension != null ? each.value.dimension : []
      content {
          name     = dimension.value.dimensionname
          operator = dimension.value.dimensionoperator
          values   = dimension.value.dimensionvalues
      }
    }
        
  }

  action {
         action_group_id = var.action_group_id
       }
```

> variable.tf

```
variable "action_group_id" {
    type = string
  description = "ID of the action group"
}


variable "resource_group_name" {
    type = string
  description = "name of the resource group"
}

/* in the variables i am passing warning as n input.is there any way i can append warning to alert name in the main.tf based on the severity value which is given down below*/
variable "kv_alert_rules" {
    type = map(object({  
     display_name = string
     # display_name = "(severity numeric equalent ex:warning)-(metric name)" 
     

     #------details for the alert criteria
     metric_name = string
     operator = string
     threshold = number 
     aggregation = string
        
    #------ dimension vaules----------
      dimension =  list(object({
        dimensionname = string
        dimensionoperator = string
        dimensionvalues = list(string)
      }))  
    #-----------------------------------
     severity = number
     frequency = string
     windowsize = string
     # window size must be gretar than Frequency values be PT1M, PT5M, PT15M, PT30M, PT1H, PT6H, PT12H and P1D. Defaults to PT5M
     
     description = string
            
    }))

    description = "This variable for alert criteria for key vault"


            default = {
     "Alert_1" = {
      # display_name = "(severity numeric equalent ex:warning)-(generic word for metric name)"
    display_name = "warning-used capacity"
    severity = 2
    dimension = null
    metric_name = "SaturationShoebox"
    aggregation = "Average"
    frequency = "PT30M"
    description = "Alert fires When Used vault capacity is GreaterThan 85"
    windowsize = "PT1H"
    operator = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 85
    }
  }
     }

variable "kv_name" {
  description = "key vault name "
  type = string 
}
```

> module calling

```
module "keyvault" {
  source = "../testing/key-vault-alert"
   alert_scope = [data.azurerm_key_vault.examplekeyvault.id]
   action_group_id = module.action-group.AGidout
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name 
   kv_name = data.azurerm_key_vault.examplekeyvault.name
}
```

I would like to make **action_group_id** as optional variable.I dont wanna reference action group ID in some instances

**If anyone knows a approach how to do that please guide me
Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action` is a dynamic block, so to make it optional you can do as follows:

```
  dynamic "action" {
     for_each = var.action_group_id != null ? [1] : []
     content {   
         action_group_id = var.action_group_id 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin its solved my issue.I tried similar approach instead of passing empty list i passed empty string **for_each = var.action_group_id != null ? var.action_group_id  : '' ''**.it showed me it cannot parse "" into the id variable. **and   for_each = var.action_group_id != null ? var.action_group_id  : []**. it produced  both condition results has to be same type.If u dont mind could you pls tell me how this solution works in background. So that i can get the essence of it

Comment: @NikhilBabuBattula No problem. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Just a small question @Marcin. action_group_id is a string. In conditional expression we are passing lists as outputs **(true== [1] and false ==empty list)**. How the conditional expression is giving string as output? if u dont mind could u tell me how it is working( it would be helpfull for me in learning)

Comment: @NikhilBabuBattula I think it would be good to make new question for the new issue with relevant code example.